# Error: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Tags: python, pytest

```
try:
        stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
        file = open('test_function.py', 'r') # i change .csv to python test file
        sys.stdin= file
        exec( file )
```

**when I was run python function.py on my function, I got this error i want to execute this function and call the function at test_function.py**

Comment: At which line the error occurs ? What's SnowBallStemmer ?

Comment: Error: name 'test_function' is not defined

Comment: "exec" expects the code itself, not a file object.

Comment: @Nineteendo no i not remove quotation 

cause the other line i have for like this;

for line in file:

Comment: "i change .csv to python test file" - wait, what? It's hard to imagine any way changing a .csv file to a .py file could make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? I believe you can just pass the file name in the exec function. This is my best guess for what to do.

```
with open("test_function-.py", "w") as file:
    # Create simplest code example, remove this when your code is working otherwise it will be overwritten!
    file.write('print("Hello, world!")')

exec(open("test_function-.py", "r").read())
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
```

Edit: I didn't use open before, I hipe you can forgive me.

Comment: Nope. This tries to look up a `test_function` variable and access a `py` attribute on the result.

Comment: Hmm..., give me a second